# How to hide a stack of modal forms in .NET Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog

I have the following problem:

I open multiple modal forms in a stack (for example, **form1 opens modal form form2 which in turn opens modal form form3**, etc.). I would like to hide the entire stack.

I tried calling the Hide method or setting the Visible property on the parent, but this only hides the parent. I also tried hiding every form individually, but then I have to call ShowDialog on each of the forms which locks the thread in which I call the aforementioned method.

Is there be a way to set the modal dialogs so that they inherit the status of the parent and get hidden in a cascade just by setting the property on the first form?

I'm also open to other suggestions.

Comment: A modal dialog means: "Please do something right now before continuing".  Having modal forms over modal forms and then wanting to just hide them means you aren't *really* using modal forms the way they were intended.  Consider revising your gui interface.

Comment: Unfortunately working around the issue by redesigning the GUI is not an option. Even if it were possible I think that the current design is valid since there may be cases where a form might have a complex functionality. Therefore, if the form that requests the user's attention has a complex enough logic the need to lock that form that locks its parent might arise as well. Besides, three levels of depth for a business process seems quite acceptable for a business application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-show a form you hid by setting `obj.Visible = false` just set `obj.Visible = true`, not `ShowDialog`.

`ShowDialog` initiates a message loop, which will cause confusion since the dialog is already running a message loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about modal dialogs, it would be the last one opened that would commence this action. Open every form as in the following example, and then `Hide()` that last one.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2.VisibleChanged += frm2_VisibleChanged;
        Shown += Form1_Shown;
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }

    void frm2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frm2.Visible == false) Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good example of cascading the Hide method call but I prefer Ben's solution since it is easier for me to set the Visible property to a list of forms than to modify the entire architecture of my application.

Comment: @Bogdan No problem. And don't forget to `Dispose` the `ShowDialog` forms. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx )